# Objective-C call a class method in runtime which the class is private

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I got a **.framework** file, and I use *class-dump* to know there is a class named `ABC` inside and don't expose anything, and `ABC` have a useful method for me, so I wonder know can I call `ABC's` method dynamic by Objective-C runtime.

Wait for your help!

Comment: Yes you can, but if you are going to submit your app to the appstore it might be rejected for using private methods.

Comment: can you show me how to write code to do this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

To create an instance of class if by it's name use [`NSClassFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJDAJA):

```
 Class myPrivateClass = NSClassFromString(@"MyPrivateClass");
 myPrivateClass  *myPrivateObj = [myPrivateClass new];
```

Now that you have the instance of the class call the select, to make it easier you can cast the instance to `NSObject`

```
 [(NSObject *)myPrivateClass performSelector:@selector(description) withObject:nil];
```

Or the class method:

```
  [myPrivateClass performSelector:@selector(description)];
```

Here I'm calling `description` on the instance and class.

Comment: Here is my code     `Class SecurityUtils = NSClassFromString(@"SecurityUtils");
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"answerChallenge:withArray:");` And I can get the class SecurityUtils, but the selector was null, can you tell me what's the problem

Comment: If the selector is null it means that it could not be create from the given string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot add `-all_load` in the field of `Other Link Flag`